# Visual Code Studio - Typescript 2.0 does not resolve/compile path based modules (shows red underline)

Tags: module, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0

I am using VSC 1.4 for my angular 2 project. I have a very simple structure as shown below and trying to setup path mapping based module resolution as mentioned here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

`projectRoot
 ├── src
 │   ├── models
 │   │   ├── modelA.ts
 │   ├── app
 │       └── modelB.ts (import {modelA} from 'src/models/modelA';)
 │
 └── tsconfig.json`

And In my tsconfig.json I have the baseURL set to `"."`

`"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  }`

But the vsc still shows a red line under the import file saying 
`[ts] cannot find module 'src/models/modelA'`

In my `package.json` I have typescript 2.

`"ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.2.2",
    "tslint": "^3.14.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.5",
    "typedoc": "^0.4.4",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",`

Can anyone tell me if I am missing something or something is not setup properly?

BTW I am using webpack. My webpack can compile it and works as expected but it is annoying to see the red line and it does not hepl in intelli-sense feature of VSCode.